# Calcular fecha con sin días inhabiles en Excel

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

Me podrían ayudar a obtener una formula o función VBA para obtener lo siguiente, por favor:

Mi primer parámetro es una fecha inicial **25/06/2019**

El segundo parámetro es descontar **120 días hábiles** (quitar sábados, domingos y una lista de días especiales (Ejemplo: Vacaciones).  )

El resultado sería

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y editar tu pregunta siguiendo [estos consejos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

En Excel ya existe una función que hace exactamente lo que dices. Se llama DIA.LAB.

> **[DIA.LAB (función DIA.LAB)](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/dia-lab-funci%C3%B3n-dia-lab-f764a5b7-05fc-4494-9486-60d494efbf33)**

Supongamos que en A1 tú tienes la fecha '25/06/2019' y quieres calcular en B1 120 días hábiles menos. Escribiríamos:

`=DIA.LAB(A1;-120)` Fíjate que como descontar fechas, he metido el número de días en negativo `-120`. Y obtenemos de resultado `08/01/2019`.

Esta función tiene un tercer argumento, opcional, que admite un rango de fechas de vacaciones, para excluirlos también de las cuentas. Podrías tener una lista con días festivos/no laborables por la razón que sea, e incluyendo ese rango en esta función, esas fechas contarían como días no hábiles).

Es exactamente lo que estás buscando.